# How to detect in WebView a 404 Error

Tags: javascript, webview, react-native

I have a `WebView` which i set the the `onError`  and the `onLoadEnd`.
The problem is that when i have a web page which returns a 404 not found error, i don't get it in the `onError` handler. I do get the `onLoadEnd` but there is no way to know that this is a 404 except the title.

[image]

Is there a way to detect that?
I was expecting that this would be handled by the `onError` callback.

Comment: i guess it could be more generic issue of how to get status code of a web page. in this case 404 but i guess it could be also interesting to know about 3xxx status like redirects.

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of react-native-webview, code is a property on the event. Make sure your web server is indeed returning an HTTP code 404, and not just a webpage that says 404 in the title.

```js
<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'https://philihp.com/it-is-a-404' }}
  onError={({ code }) => {
    console.log({ code });
  }}
/>
```